# Laravel external app login session does not persist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I'm trying to do a login function in a external app, its works but the session does not persists when refresh.

```
function laravelLogin($id)
{
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)
        ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

    $user = $app->make('App\Models\User')
                    ->where('id',$id)
                    ->first();

    $app->Auth::login($user);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `Auth::login($user, true)` according [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods) that should login and remember the user

Comment: Thanks, I just try but its doesn't work @milo526

Comment: You need to debug whether the session was in fact lost, or whether the session lost the authorized user information.  There is a lot to be said about sessions and Laravel, and unfortunately, in my opinion, they should not be relied on, as it is perfectly possible to loose session information if you have multiple processes that update the session simultaneously (which can happen when doing some ajax calls for instance).  I would suggest you debug first to see if the entire session is lost, or that just the auth party within is lost.  In the latter case, I suggest moving to token based auth

Comment: @DavidHeremans thanks, yes, it's gonna be the next try

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: hi @DavidHeremans, i finally use https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport Thanks.